# my app was rejected for ubuntu touch store due to 'unconfined'

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development

I got a message from the review process

> The moderators noted the issue to be addressed as follows:
>
> security_template_valid (compass.apparmor):
>
> (MANUAL REVIEW) 'unconfined' not allowed

I have been accessing the /sys/devices/platform/msensor/driver/sensordata to read the values from the magnetic sensor (qt libraries do not work so I had to take direct approach in reading sensor status). However apparmor does not allow reading from file even by setting

> "read_path": [
>           "/sys/devices/platform/msensor/driver/"
>       ],

Is there any easy way to overcome that problem, to get a simple compass application to a store I have programmed, the code is open ...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First, the error message that you quote suggests that the problem is not with the specific read path, but that you're using the 'unconfined' profile.  Instead, you should be using the standard confined profile with the additional read path, so that the permissions are as limited as possible.

Once you do that, you may get a rejection that says,

> found redflagged fields (needs human review): read_path

At this point, you can request a manual review.  I think there will be a link or a button on the "Feedback" page of your app's myapp.developer.ubuntu.com site, but it might be hiding somewhere else.  There is, unfortunately, no timetable for the manual review process.  You may want to go into #ubuntu-touch and bug someone to take a look at it.

Eventually someone will decide whether or not to allow this.  I don't know what criteria are used to judge these reviews.  My guess is that if your app is pure QML it will be accepted, since they can examine your code to check that it doesn't do anything nefarious.  I'm less sure of what will happen with compiled code.

If the official app store doesn't accept your app, you may wish to submit it to the [Open App Store](https://open.uappexplorer.com/), which exists to hold useful apps that can't live under the restrictions of the official store.